# Keeping and updating ACF and ACF Pro at the same time

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I am not sure how far this is relevant on this platform. Actually I am in a situation where I have both `ACF` *(Deactivated)* and `ACF Pro` **(Activated)** installed at the same time in a single WordPress site.

The Pro version is running the latest (**v 5.12**). But the Non-pro version is falling behind a few (minor) updates. Current version is **5.11** to be exact.

I am a bit confused about updating the `ACF` (non pro) version because it is deactivated and ideally should not create any problem. But at the same time, keeping an old plugin, whether it is activated or not, is not recommended. And, at the same time hesitating to remove it completely for any unwanted impact!

Is this safe to update / remove the plugin? What should be the correct way to test for any impact that might happen if I remove the non-pro version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the free is deactivated, the code inside is not used. You can delete it.
ACF Pro is embedding ACF free functions so no worries.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the precise and hitting-the-dot reply!